# In a discrete metric space, every subset is open. Isn't this a contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Many people argue that in a discrete metric space $(X,d)$ every subset is open (and closed). The most common argument is that, for every subset $E \subset X$ let $x \in E$ and take $0<r<1$, then the ball $B(x;r) = \{ x \}$ so that is open and, therefore, the union of all such subsets is open. But wouldn't that be a contradiction? Because it can be shown that every point of every open subset of any metric space is a limit point, which means that every ball must contain at least one point of the subset other than itself, and in this case the ball $B(x;r)$ only contains its center, contradicting the fact that it should be a limit point of $E$ (since $E$ is open).

Comment: This argument doesn't make any sense.  In a discrete space, it is not true that every ball must contain "at least one point of the subset other than itself."  After all, you've already argued that $\{x\}$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be shown that every point of every open subset of any metric space is a limit point. For instance, in *any* discrete metric space $X$, *no* point $x$ is a limit point of any subset $A$ of $X$, since $B_1(x)=\{x\}$, and therefore $B_1(x)\cap A$ is either $\emptyset$ or $\{x\}$. And, by definition of limit point, if $x$ was a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $x$ would have an element of $A$ distinct from $x$ itself.